# Run angular 2/4 application permanently on live server

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

Hi i want to know that how to run angular application permanently. means if i run the npm start command on local server. then after it gives a url with port like **localhost:4200**. but when i close the terminal then my project not run.
Same thing happen with me on live server when i run my command through putty.
**ng serve --host {ipadddress}**. then it gives me a URL like **mysiteip:4200**. but when i close putty my site not run. i want to know that how to run  angular application permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You could just send process into background by adding &

Comment: thanks asdfgh but how to send process into background..?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

forever start node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --host {ip_address or domain} --prod

Reference - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4951

Instead of this, You can build your app and just drop everything you got in dist folder of your angular app into the directory of the hosting platform.

Comment: it is working. thanks Krishna Sahu. that is what i was looking for.

Comment: Cheers Irshad !

Comment: one more thing  Krishna Sahu. that how can i stop or restart that process again...?.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359290/command-to-stop-infinte-running-angular-server/49359871#49359871
Irshad. Check out this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the `screen` command on linux/unix systems

```
screen
// New shell opens

ng serve --host {ipadddress}
// Now putty can be closed
```

This is a terminal that persists and can be continued.

```
screen -r
// Lists all active screen sessions

screen -r SCREEN_TTY_NO
```

But I would advise to not use this in a productive environment.

Comment: Thanks Bernhard. i got the solution. thanks for your time and intrest