# Command to Stop infinte running Angular Server

Tags: angular, forever

I used the following command to create a never ending angular server and it's working.

```
forever start node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --host {ip_address or domain} --prod
```

But what is the command to stop this infinite running server?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701259/how-to-make-a-node-js-application-run-permanently/49320380#49320380

Comment: Thanks Sudhir. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign an id

```
forever start --uid "serve" node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --host {ip_address or domain} --prod
```

Then you can use that id to stop it

```
forever stop serve
```

Just to clarify, `ng serve` uses webpack dev server, it's not suited for production